# Graph the straight line corresponding to the rule (y=7x) for 0≤x≤15

Tags: linear-algebra, relations

I have attempted this question but I don't really know where to even start. I have graphed y=7x but i'm not sure where to go from there. I am a bit stuck on graphing a line that is relating to 0≤x≤15.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The statement $0\le x\le 15$ mean that you must draw $y=7x$ only for values of x from $0$ to $15$.

Comment: Note then that wont be a straight line it would become a segment

Comment: You may look at the solution as an intersection of a straight line and vertical zone.

Comment: okay thanks for that, what would the coordinates for the line segment?

Comment: I have drawn y=7x onto the graph and i'm a bit stuck on how you use the values to create a line segment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $x=0$ then, as we're given $y=7x$, so we get $$y=7\times 0=0$$ Therefore we have an initial point on the plane: $A=(0,0)$. The same story can be done for $x=15$ to find another point which is $B=(15,7\times 15)=(15,105)$. Now draw the line $y=7x$ first and then bold the line between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: thanks for that, much appreciated. I'm still a bit unsure about the 0≤x≤15

Comment: Thanks. Why? What are you worried about?

Comment: just how you interpret it into the graph